# jQuery, only apply click event to appended for each item

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('div > .card-body > .text-muted').append('<div class="card-body" style="background-color:#292b2e;border-radius:5px;">'+data+'<a class="btn btn-secondary">Sell</a></div>').last().on('click', function(){
  console.log("SellClicked " + hatassetid);
  window.location.href = "https://domain/asset/"+assetid+"/sell";
});
```

I'm stumped trying to resolve jQuery script that appends new buttons that are clickable to do an action. The buttons do show up, and they all are clickable. However, when I click one of the buttons, all the buttons that were appended, runs the SellClicked function, ending up in the last found item to only be able to run every time, no matter which button I click.

Is there a more reliable way to append a clickable button with a click function?

Output always responds.

> SellClicked 84600 SellClicked 84683 SellClicked 84703 SellClicked
>   85056 SellClicked 85488 SellClicked 86296 SellClicked 87379
>   SellClicked 88709 SellClicked 90299 SellClicked 96525

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A working snippet would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `console.log($(this))` on  from within your `.on`, you'll find it's returning the parent element, `.text_muted`, and not the button. This is due to the `.on()` method being applied to the selector, `$("div > .card-body > .text-muted")`, not the buttons.

What this implies is, your buttons aren't actually working, it's the event listeners on the '.text_muted' working (tested and confirmed this). It also implies you're creating a new event listener for this parent element for each iteration of your loop, thus the repeated outputs.

To resolve this, I would drop the ".last().on()", add a class to your button while appending it and create an event listener for it:

```
$('div > .card-body > .text-muted').append('<div class="card-body" style="background-color:#292b2e;border-radius:5px;">'+data+'<a class="btn btn-secondary myButtonClass">Sell</a></div>')

$(".myButtonClass").click(function(){
     <do something>
})
```

**Bonus:**
Your code is a little incomplete, so we can't be sure of where 'hatassetid' is coming from, but if you're needing to pass data with a button click, you can just add the asset ID (or whatever) as a "data-" attribute and access it from the event listener function:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary myButtonClass" data-assetId='+assetID+'></a>
```

and then:

```
$(".myButtonClass").click(function(){
         var assetId = this.data('assetid') //please note, data() attributes must be selected using all lowercase characters
     })
```

[See it in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssWDvtdAXO2KiaCZB9ZH?p=preview)